# regex ip address from string

Tags: c, regex

gcc 4.6.2 c89

Is there any standard regex expression that can be used to extract the IP address from a string.

I am thinking about using sscanf with a regex expression to get the IP from this sample string below.

This is the sample string:

```
v=0 o=sip_user IN 10230 22472 IP4 NET.CAT.NTBC s=SIP_CALL c=IN IP4 10.10.10.44 m=audio 49152 RTP/AVP 0 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
```

So the regex will be in between the quotes:

```
sscanf(ip_string, "%s", &ip_address);
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: `sscanf()` doesn't take a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks I did see that regular regex expression. But my problem is how can I get that to work in c? What standard c function do I insert it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your OS for regex.h and use the defined regular expression library. e.g. [linux example](http://linuxgazette.net/issue55/tindale.html)