# Using R for regex IP address in text

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am attempting to parse a data frame that has text in each row and within that text there are IP addresses I want to isolate.  However, I am still picking up integers, whole numbers and periods.  Below is a example of what I am working with.

```
    z <- data.frame( x =  c('112.68.196.98   5.32', '192.41.196.888', '..','5.32  88'))
    gsub("^\\.+|\\.[^.]*$", "", z$x, perl=TRUE)
```

I am looking to clean this dataframe so the output would just be:

```
    z <- data.frame( x =  c('112.68.196.98', '192.41.196.888','',''))
```

I can't seem to come up with the proper regex to put into the gsub. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex ip address from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439633/regex-ip-address-from-string)

Comment: R uses slightly different syntax.  Not a duplicate, just very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
re <- regexpr(
  "(?(?=.*?(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+).*?)(\\1|))", 
  z$x, perl = TRUE)

regmatches(z$x, re)
#[1] "112.68.196.98"  "192.41.196.888" ""               ""
```

---

This uses a regex conditional, keeping the capture group (`\\1`) in the case of a positive match on `.*?(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+).*?`, else returning an empty result.

---

**Update:**

Regarding your comment, I think the following changes will allow you to capture multiple IP addresses in a single string. First, switch from `regexpr` to `gregexpr` to allow multiple results:

```
re2 <- gregexpr(
  "(?(?=.*?(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+).*?)(\\1|))", 
  z2$x, perl = TRUE
)
```

Since calling `regmatches` on a `gregexpr` input will return a list, some additional processing is required:

```
res2 <- sapply(regmatches(z2$x, re2), function(x) {
  gsub(
    "^\\s+|\\s+$", "", 
    gsub("\\s+", " ", paste0(x, collapse = " "))
  )
}
```

This should be suitable for, e.g., recombining with your `data.frame` as a new column:

```
res2
#[1] "112.68.196.98 192.41.196.888" "192.41.196.888"               
#     ""                             "112.68.196.98"
```

---

And if you *did* want to break out each result into its own string, the expression is a little simpler (compared to `sapply(...)`):

```
lapply(regmatches(z2$x, re2), function(x) {
  Filter(function(y) y != "", x)
})
#[[1]]
#[1] "112.68.196.98"  "192.41.196.888"

#[[2]]
#[1] "192.41.196.888"

#[[3]]
#character(0)

#[[4]]
#[1] "112.68.196.98"
```

---

**Data:**

```
z2 <- data.frame(
  x = c('112.68.196.98 5.32 192.41.196.888', 
        '192.41.196.888', 
        '..', '5.32 88 112.68.196.98'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Thanks nrussell.  This works well.  One more question, if I had multiple IPs in the same cell, how would I modify this to capture 1 or more IPs.  For example:
    z <- data.frame( x =  c('112.68.196.98 5.32 192.41.196.888',
                         '192.41.196.888',
                         '..',
                         '5.32 88 112.68.196.98'))

Comment: Should multiple ips be split into their own string, or remain combined (e.g. separated by a space)?

Comment: For the purposes of my project, I am keeping them combined into one cell/element (separated by a space) and I will break them out later.  I want them to keep their associated index.  Thanks.